# Meaning of "==>" syntax in F#

Tags: f#, fscheck

Consider the following code in F#

```
let rec ordered xs = 
    match xs with
      | [] | [_]        -> true
      | x1 :: x2 :: xs'  -> x1 <= x2 && ordered (x2 :: xs')
```

and then

```
let rec insert x xs = 
    match xs with
    | []      -> [x]
    | y :: ys -> if x <= y then x :: y :: ys 
                 else           y :: insert x ys
```

and finally

```
let insertKeepsOrder (x : int) xs = ordered xs ==> ordered (insert x xs)
```

What i can not understand is the `==>` meanning in the last line!!!

What is it?

Comment: It's not a built-in operator. What 3rd party assemblies are you referencing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `==>` operator is part of [FsCheck](https://fscheck.github.io/FsCheck/index.html). It is used to express a property that should hold *only if some condition is true*.

So in your example:

```
let insertKeepsOrder (x : int) xs = ordered xs ==> ordered (insert x xs)
```

This means `ordered (insert x xs)` should be true only if `ordered xs` is true.

You can read more about this in [the "Conditional Properties" section of the FsCheck documentation](https://fscheck.github.io/FsCheck/Properties.html).

Comment: In the general case, you can also right-click and "Go to Definition" on the operator if you have VS 2015 and F# Power Tools installed. That will at least show you metadata indicating in which library the operator is defined, so you know where to look for documentation.